# when should I use JFrame.add(component) and JFrame.getContentPane().add(component) in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, frame

Is there a difference between them and are there any conditions in which one should be used instead of the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand from Javadocs, JFrame.add calls the latter. It is a convenience method to get around the incompatibility between AWT's frame and Swings JFrame.

From [javadocs for JFrame](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html):

> The JFrame class is slightly incompatible with Frame. Like all other
>   JFC/Swing top-level containers, a JFrame contains a JRootPane as its
>   only child. The content pane provided by the root pane should, as a
>   rule, contain all the non-menu components displayed by the JFrame.
>   This is different from the AWT Frame case. As a conveniance add and
>   its variants, remove and setLayout have been overridden to forward to
>   the contentPane as necessary. This means you can write:
>
> ```
>    `frame.add(child);`
> ```
>
> And the child will be added to the
>   contentPane. The content pane will always be non-null. Attempting to
>   set it to null will cause the JFrame to throw an exception. The
>   default content pane will have a BorderLayout manager set on it. Refer
>   to RootPaneContainer for details on adding, removing and setting the
>   LayoutManager of a JFrame.

Answer (score 14):

Both calls are the same. In Java 5, they changed `jframe.add` to forward calls to the content pane.

From the [Java 5 release notes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/relnotes/features.html#swing):

> Lastly, after seven years, we've made jFrame.add equivalent to
>   jFrame.getContentPane().add().

Also, see the [javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html).

Answer (score 4):

if your question is only about `JFrame#add(JComponent)` v.s. `JFrame.getContentPane()#add(JComponent)` then there isn't difference, but if you want to change f.e. BackGround then depends if you call methods from `JFrame#setBackground(Color)` or nested or inherits methods from awt.Frame `JFrame.getContentPane()#setBackground(Color)` ...

Answer (score 3):

`add()` will forward the work to `addImpl()` for which the JavaDoc of `JFrame` states the following:

> By default, children are added to the contentPane instead of the frame.

Thus, both methods have the same basic behaviour, besides the fact that using `getContentPane().add(...)` is more explicit.

Note that you could alter the default behaviour for add (using `setRootPaneCheckingEnabled(false)`), but I'm not sure you'd want to do that.