# Trying to add text field below table in GUI in java

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea, jframe

The code I have currently works but only displays the table. I'm trying to add a text field below it but I'm not sure how I would do it. I'm also trying to set a listener on the text field and I'm not too sure how to do that either. Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm not experienced in Java forms

```
public class table extends JFrame {
    JTable TestDB;
    public table(){
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        String[] columnNames={"First Name","Last Name","Address"};
        Object[][] data={{"Bob","Hazel","HelpMeDr"},{"Yo","Whattup","ezpz"}};

        TestDB=new JTable(data,columnNames);
        TestDB.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500,50));
        TestDB.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        JScrollPane scrollPane=new JScrollPane(TestDB);
        add(scrollPane);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a text field using the next code

```
textField = new JTextField(20);

//add a listener 
textField.addActionListener(this);
```

Now for make something happend after interact with the text field you need to make a method

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    //do this when action performed at the textfield
}
```

I recommend you to visit the next website for more information https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html

Answer (score 0):

fist of all

- do not extend `JFrame` 
  here is [why you should not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003802/extends-jframe-vs-creating-it-inside-the-program)
- `set a listener on the text field` you don't !! you add a listener , huge difference . @P Dev answer is clear and neat in the listener matter.
- do not use `add` directly with the frame object instead use `getContentPane().add` and the same goes on with the `setLayout` method because you don't really use it on the frame it self and it might crash your application in many cases . see [when should I use JFrame.add(component) and JFrame.getContentPane().add(component) in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554125/when-should-i-use-jframe-addcomponent-and-jframe-getcontentpane-addcomponen)

last thing , in simple words , the `FlowLayout` is meant to be used only when you are aligning your components in horizontally as if it's a text in lines .

instead use another layout like `BoxLayout`
like this

```
    public Table() {
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        String[] columnNames = {"First Name", "Last Name", "Address"};
        Object[][] data = {{"Bob", "Hazel", "HelpMeDr"}, {"Yo", "Whattup", "ezpz"}};

        TestDB = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        TestDB.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 50));
        TestDB.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(TestDB);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        getContentPane().add(textField);
    }
```

and one last thing is that text components have not less than 10 types of listener you have to use the one that fit your needs,our friend' answer(which i upvoted ) suggested that you will use `ActionListener` which it will be invoked every time the user hit 'Enter' in the text field .
see [How to Use BoxLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) for better understanding of the layout matter and happy coding ^-^.